# Inexplicable space (margin?) below H1

Tags: jquery, css, margin

For some reason I've got a ton of space below the H1 tag on [this page](http://staging.lifestylerevolutionstx.com/fitness-videos.html). When the H1 is removed, the extra space is removed, but I have not been able to isolate the code causing this. I applied a margin of 0 with !important and this had no effect.

```
<div class="videoGallery large-12 columns">

    <h1>Fitness Videos</h1>

    <div class="videoPreviewBox">
        <a class="video1" href="#">
            <div class="videoPreview">
                <img class="videoPreviewImg" src="img/promo/groupFitness.jpg">
                <img class="playButtonHover" src="../img/playButtonHover.png">
                <img class="playButton" src="../img/playButton.png">
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.videoGallery h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  line-height: 24px;
}

div.videoPreviewBox {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 21%;
  margin: 0% 2%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 594px) {
  div.videoPreviewBox {
    width: 46%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  div.videoPreviewBox {
    width: 96%;
  }
}

div.videoPreview { 
  position: relative;
}

img.videoPreviewImg {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

img.playButtonHover, img.playButton {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-left: -24px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
}

div.videoPreview:hover img.playButton {
  opacity: 0;
}

div.videoPreviewBox p {
  margin: 2% 0% 4% 0%;
  color: white;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

I thought at first the issue might be caused by a jQuery plugin, equalHeights, which is used to make the all of the boxes containing a preview image and description paragraph the same height, but if that were the case then the open space would also be duplicated between the two rows.

Any pointers are very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: You have 2 H1 tags in your code. You can only have 1.

Comment: @putvande not true as of HTML5

Comment: From SEO point of view you can't have two `h1` tags on one page. Either way it's valid code.

Answer (score 4):

The element has a `min-height` inline style of 184px. That's obviously going to make it take up a lot of space.

I believe it has been added by the equalHeights plugin, which you're calling like this:

```
$(function(){ $('.videoGallery').equalHeights(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with your jQuery plugin, the min-height of your H1 is set to 148px, the same height as your video preview divs.

Change this

```
$(function(){ $('.videoGallery').equalHeights(); });
```

to

```
$(function(){ $('.videoGallery div').equalHeights(); });
```

If this won't work, place your H1 above the div with class videoGallery.

Comment: I just realised you spotted the root cause of the problem long before I did. You really deserve the votes more than I do. I hope my +1 is at least some consolation.

Comment: No problem, the question is answered ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
.videoGallery h1 {
color: white;
font-size: 24px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 !important;
line-height: 50px;
clear: both;
display: inline;
}
```

Notice the `line-height` and the `display` properties

Answer (score 0):

You have `min-height: 184px` declared inline on your `<h1/>`. Either remove the inline style, or `.videoGallery h1 { min-height: 0 !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

Upon inspecting your page with FireBug I can see that you have this:

```
<h1 **style="min-height: 184px;"**>Fitness Videos</h1>
```

You need to change the min-height to something smaller or remove it alltogether and put it in a css.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be coming from

```
div.videoPreviewBox {
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 21%;
      **margin: 0% 2%;**
}
```

You see it has a margin above and below the element. That margin may be collapsing when the h1 is gone but returned when it has an element to push off of.